# create a select option dropdown based on the tables content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Below is my snippet that creates a select option dropdown base on the data present on the table, it works fine instead I want to not duplicate the option e.g. if already have "medicine 1 or option value medicine_1" then do not add again, in short if same option exist then do not append. Any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("table tr").each(function () {
            $("select").append('<option value="' + $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") + '">' + $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text() + '<option>');
        });

    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
<button>create</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id 1</td>
        <td>medicine 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id 1</td>
        <td>medicine 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id 1</td>
        <td>medicine 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id 1</td>
        <td>medicine 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>id 1</td>
        <td>medicine 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if there is already an option with dupe value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
      if ($("select").find('option[value=' + value + ']').length) return;
      $("select").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text() + '</option>');
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
<button>create</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: seems like there's an appended option with an empty text or values. Any ideas?

Comment: Ya this is fixed, your code was appending two optios at once,  missing closing tag

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a function to check whether this value already exists on the dropdown or not:

```
var optionExists = function optionExists(select, value) {
  var found = false;
  select.find('option').each(function(option) {
    if ($(this).val() === value && !found) {
      found = true;
    }

  });
  return found;
}
```

It's very simple, you only need to check for the value by looping through all existant option on the dropdown, before appending a new option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
      if (!optionExists($("select"), value)) {
        $("select").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text() + '</option>');

      }
    });

  });
})

var optionExists = function optionExists(select, value) {
  var found = false;
  select.find('option').each(function(option) {
    if($(this).val() === value && !found){
      found = true;   
    }

  });
  return found;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select>


</select>


<button>create</button>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $("table tr").each(function() {
      var option = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
      if ($.inArray(option, arr) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
        arr.push(option);

        $("select").append('<option  value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>');
      }
    });

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select>


</select>


<button>create</button>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id 1</td>
    <td>medicine 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try like this 
Create an array. Check if the value exist in array if not add the value to array and into the option if exist don't append.

***UPDATE***

as **@balachandar** notice you have problem with closing the option in select

Comment: seems like, there's an added option that has no text nor value. any ideas?

Comment: Please close the option tag while appending the option tag like **</option>**. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k8ht9ass/

Comment: it is the way you add the option i change the way you add your option it works now @CodeDemon

Comment: @balachandar i didnt notice that. i will add that to update

Answer (score 0):

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4tsLot4/1/) using **.unique()**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("button").click(function(){
          var items=[], options=[];

            //Iterate all td's in second column
            $('td:nth-child(2)').each( function(){
               //add item to array
               items.push( $(this).text() );       
            });

            //restrict array to unique items
            var items = $.unique( items );

            //iterate unique array and build array of select options
            $.each( items, function(i, item){
                options.push('<option value="' + item.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_") + '">' + item + '</option>');
            });

            //finally empty the select and append the items from the array
            $('select').empty().append( options.join() );

      });
});
```